# C# Store A List As a Comma Separated String In String Type Variable With Number Of Occurrence Of Items In The List

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, generics

I have a list `List<Book> booksList` of type `Book`

```
public class Book
{
public int ID {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public DateTime date {get; set;}

}
```

lets say we have 8 books in this list with following Names, 
`book1, book2, book1, book4,book2, book4, book3, book4` .
As you see so many same book name with different ID is in the list.
I want to store similar book names with multiplication of number of occurrence of that book name in the list  inside a string variable called `string BooksName` as a comma separated string, so when I retrieve `BooksName` i will have one comma separated string value like this

```
"2 X book1 , 2 X book2 , 1 X book3 , 3 X book4"
```

Because I have 2 of book1, 2 of book2, 1 of book3 and 3 of book4 in the list.

I tried following linq but it did not work

```
string BooksName = booksList.GroupBy(r =>r.Name).Select(s => s.Select(e =>e.Name).Count() + " X " + s.Name).ToString();
```

After 
How can I do that?

Thank you professionals in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to order the results of `GroupBy`, modify how you are selecting the book name for display, and use `string.Join()`.

```
void Main()
{
    var booksList = new List<Book>();
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book1" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book2" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book1" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book4" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book2" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book4" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book3" });
    booksList.Add(new Book { Name = "book4" });

    string BooksName = string.Join(", ", booksList
        .GroupBy(r =>r.Name)
        .OrderBy(r => r.First().Name)
        .Select(s => s.Count() + " X " + s.First().Name));

    Console.WriteLine(BooksName);
    // Output: 2 X book1, 2 X book2, 1 X book3, 3 X book4
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @CodeGorilla If answer helps you, please accept it.

Comment: I did .... Oh sorry I thought I need to just click up it, Ill click on tick mark now, I'm pretty new here

Answer (score 1):

You can't just `.ToString` an enumerable, you need to use `string.Join` instead:.

```
var booksList = "book1, book2, book1, book4,book2, book4, book3, book4".Split(',')
    .Select(x => new Book { Name = x.Trim() })
    .ToList();

var BooksName = string.Join(", ", booksList
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => $"{g.Count()} X {g.Key}")
);
```